# Cleaning and vectorization of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-preprocessing

I don't know how to clean and vectorize data.

```
train=pd.read_csv('longilati.csv',encoding='mac_roman')
train`
Index(['Comment ', 'Polarity'], dtype='object')
```

The following data is in my dataframe:

[image]

But, whenever I try to clean data using following code

```
def remove_pattern(text,pattern):     
    r = re.findall(pattern,text)    
        for i in r:
        text = re.sub(i,"",text)
        return text
train['Tidy'] = np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(train['Comment'],"@[\w]*")
train
```

I get this error `KeyError: 'Comment'`
Here is the full stacktrace of it

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, 
key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, 
key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return 
self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, 
tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Comment'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have space after `comment` in your column name.
Either replace column name using

```
df.rename({'Comment ':'Comment'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

or use

```
np.vectorize(remove_pattern)(train['Comment '],"@[\w]*")
```

Comment: I agree its a naming issue. If its in the original source, I would suggest fixing it there if possible, else doing a rename in processing is acceptable.

Comment: thanks a lot  @Smurphy0000 It helped me... I am new to data science so did not knew about this type of error.